# Performing Inverse Distance Weighted (IDW) interpolation in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, inverse-distance-weighted

I would like to know if interpolation like in the image below is possible to produce in earth engine. Can someone tell how to get it done because I can only do it in ArcGIS and QGIS. I found this https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/interpolation but I don't think it's the right one because I have a map, and precipitation in points.

[image]

Comment: can You put the code (GEE) please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually solved this a month ago. See the below image with code.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.
You have to edit the existing fusion table with your coordinates and replace arithmetic mean with the precipitation values.

Comment: thanks for the comment, but I already solved this a month ago.